# Check date format style in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdateformatter

How can we check date in which format I am getting response from API and in which getting dates I am converting date from string according to format but confusion is getting date in two format, `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` and `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` some include `SSS` and some are not, kindly tell me how can first I check date format style and then use date format according to that.

Here following I am using code for converting string into my desired format.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"2016-01-18T13:28:06.357";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
```

Looking for your response.

Comment: Try one format. If it fails, try the other format.

Answer (score 2):

initially Check like

```
NSDate *date;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 // Initially check like   2016-01-18T13:28:06.357
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
// it returns the date ,
 date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
 // check if date is empty or 
 if(date == nil) {
  // add the another date format 
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
  date = [formatter dateFromString:dateStr];
}
```

Comment: do you think this is good solution, what if date format can be some other format too, so then i'll have to add another format.

Comment: @Aleem -- but your condition is satisfy only two based on two I implement

Answer (score 0):

Pass your API response `Date` as string and check what is the format of your date. If it doesn't match any formate then you can return any other format which you want.

```
- (NSString*) isFirstTypeDate: (NSString*) theString
    {
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];
         NSDate *dateFromString = [NSDate date];

        dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:theString];

        if (dateFromString !=nil) {
            return @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS";
        }
        else {

            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];

            dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:theString];

            if (dateFromString !=nil) {

                return @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";

            }else{

            return @"Default Date formate you want";

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy for your advice. :)